# Kafka Streams use case

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am building a simple application which does below in order -

1) Reads messages from a remote IBM MQ(legacy system only works with IBM MQ)

2) Writes these messages to Kafka Topic

3) Reads these messages from the same Kafka Topic and calls a REST API.

4) There could be other consumers reading from this topic in future.

I came to know that Kafka has the new streams API which is supposed to be better than Kafka consumer in terms of speed/simplicity etc. Can someone please let me know if the streams API is a good fit for my use case and at what point in my process i can plug it  ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> 1. Reads messages from a remote IBM MQ (legacy system only works with
>    IBM MQ)
> 2. Writes these messages to Kafka Topic

I'd use [Kafka Connect](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/connect/index.html#kafka-connect) for (1) and (2). It is part of the Kafka project, and there are many free as well as commercial "connectors" available for hundreds of systems.

> 3. Reads these messages from the same Kafka Topic and calls a REST API.

You can use [Kafka Streams](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/streams/index.html) as well as the lower-level Consumer API of Kafka, depending on what you prefer. I'd go with Kafka Streams as it is easier to use and far more powerful. (Both are part of the Kafka project.)

> 4. There could be other consumers reading from this topic in future.

This works out-of-the-box -- once data is stored in a Kafka topic according to step 2, many different applications and "consumers" can read this data independently.

Answer (score 12):

It is true that Kafka Streams API has a simple way to consume records in comparison to Kafka Consumer API (e.g. you don't need to poll, manage a thread and loop), but it also comes with a cost (e.g. local data store - if you do stateful processing).

I would say that if you need to consume records one by one and call a REST API use the Consumer API, if you need stateful processing, query the topic state, etc. use the Streams API.

For more info take a look to this blog post: https://balamaci.ro/kafka-streams-for-stream-processing/

Comment: FYI: The Kafka Streams API does not force you to use state stores or do stateful processing.  You can also do stateless processing, of course (and thus don't need to pay the "cost" of local state stores).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are not doing any processing/transformation once you consume you message from your IBM MQ or even after your Kafka Topic.

First one -> from IBM Mq to your Kafka Topic is kind of a pipeline and
Secondly -> You are just calling the REST API(I assume w/o any processing)

Considering these facts it seems to be a good fit for using Simple consumer.

Let's not use a technology only because it's there :)